# unable to deploy a basic react app on elastic beanstalk

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created a simple react-app and I was able to run it locally. However I am unable to deploy the app on elastic beanstalk using `eb cli` or manually.

There seems to be no node server running, hence the health checks were failing.
How can I resolve this error?

> Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Degraded. Initialization completed 6 seconds ago and took 2 minutes. Impaired services on all instances.

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have also noticed the following message

> Instance deployment: You didn't specify a Node.js version in the 'package.json' file in your source bundle. The deployment didn't install a specific Node.js version.

So I have updated the `package.json` with the following, however it didn't help.

```json
 "engines" : { 
    "npm" : ">=8.0.0 <9.0.0",
    "node" : ">=16.0.0 <17.0.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was using node.js when I deploy. Instead I should use docker with nginx.

```yaml
FROM node:17.1-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.22.1-alpine as prod-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

After building the docker image, we should use `eb cli` to deploy by executing the following commands `eb init` and `eb create`.